# what is process.env

Tags: node.js

Where can I get the documentation for `process.env`?

Wat all the variables I can access in that env

For example, what does  `process.env.port || 1137` do?

I understand process.env is environment and we are looking for port in it. what does `||` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common notation in JavaScript that allows for default values, typically for user provided options, if none are given.

If `process.env.port` has a value, it is used.  If it doesn't have a value, then 1137 will be used.

Answer (score 0):

if `process.env.port` exist it will use it otherwise it will use 1137. `||` it is or operator.